# Symfony2 Session Timeout: cookie_lifetime not working

Tags: php, session, symfony, session-cookies

I have the following configuration:

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         
      cookie_lifetime: 43200
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
```

For some reason, the cookie_lifetime parameter is being respected on my local server as well of a development server of my own, but on the production server the session is being killed after some time (an hour I think), logging out the user.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if `cookie_lifetime` maybe set in `config_prod.yml`? Did you also clear your cache for production?

Comment: It's not set on config_prod and I've cleared the cache. The weird thing here isn't that is logging out the user on prod and not on dev, is that on three different servers (local, hosting a, hosting b) is having different behavior: on two of them keeps logged in and on the other one the user is kicked out after some time.

Comment: Check session time out in the php.ini on each server

Comment: The only differences between the two files are: session.gc_divisor =1000 (Local) = 100 (Prod); session.hash_bits_per_character = 5 (Local) = 4 (Prod); session.save_path = C:\xampp\tmp (Local) = no value (Prod). Not setting a save path should produce something like this?

Comment: The session files are being stored in app/cache/prod/sessions, so I doubt that it have to do with that. What I've noticed is that while session files last more than one hour on local server, I can't seem to find a single file that lasts more than one hour on production server, it seems that something is deleting (or forcing to recreate) the files after an hour.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? got the same here :/

Comment: Nope, I think it maybe had to do with DigitalOcean or Symfony version (2.3). With 2.7+ and usng AWS, never had that problem again.